# Is it possible to determine an instruction's timespan?

Tags: c, assembly, timespan, aslr

I have a question, which I was unable to Google because I really don't know the proper terminology for it, if concept exists that is. My question is this;

Imagine having a while loop in C, which does 1 inline assembly instruction

```
__asm { mov eax, ebp };
```

Then we would print it's output with printf, respectively. But would it be possible to determine when "time" has reached exactly 1 second?

I'm doing some research on ASLR, and I want to see if there is a fixed timespan between each randomization by seeing if the randomization occures exactly X seconds apart from each other.

Hope you understand, and thanks for reading/helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address space does not get randomized after the process is started.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that. Nevermind my question then... Thank you. =)